# How i can Pass data from adotable to fast report in delphi 10 seattle

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, fastreport

I have **Delphi 10 seattle** & i have a `Form1` ,in the `Form` i have :

- `ADOConnection1`
- `ADOTable1`
- `DBGrid1`
- `frxreport1`

**How can i pass the data from the table into the report & show the report ?**

Thank you.

Comment: Read the FR manual. This is not a tutorial site. You can find the manual on the FR website.

Comment: Okey thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Add TfrxDBDataset to project, assign it with TADOTable, go to FR's designer and enable TfrxDBDataset (menu Report-Data), add TfrxMasterdata band to report template, assign it with TfrxDBDataset, place TfrxMemoView on TfrxMasterData band, assign TfrxMemoView with TfrxDBDataset field